# During CSS Animation (Bootstrap 5 collapse) margin-collaps gets disabled causing a Jittery animation

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

### Example

Here is a simple example:

```css
.mynav {
  margin-top: 36px;
}

li {
  margin: 18px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseNav">
    BURGER
</button>
<ul class="mynav navigation collapse show" id="collapseNav" style="">
  <li>
    a
  </li>
  <li>
    b
  </li>
  <li>
    c
  </li>
  <li>
    d
  </li>
  <li>
    e
  </li>
</ul>
```

### The Problem

During the animation, the top-margins of `ul` and `li` stop collapsing.

Is this intended?
How can I work around that?
Is this a bug in bootstrap 5?

### Update: Workaround

Everything works fine if I put all collapsable in a wrapper-container.
I don't understand why that is necessary.

<del>Also this leads to a different problem: The container can not be a HTML custom element. I assume that this is a bug. So I created a bugreport: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32828
But that is just a side note.</del>

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the reason:

When animating, bootstrap changes `overflow` from `visible` to `hidden`.
`Overflow: hidden` adds a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).
In a block formatting context, the outermost element has no margin collapse.
So by animating, the margins stop collapsing and the list starts jittering.

### Solution:

1. Avoid margin collapsing.

*or*

2. Add a wrapping container and animate the container.

Comment: Same problem for me but i did add one wrapper to the collapse component (i'm using react) but it's still clunky can you suggest a snippet?